# Применение слова "всеразличный"

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

Возможно ли использовать слово "всеразличный" в современном русском языке, или же это устаревшее слово, которое не следует применять?

Comment: Я не нашел такого слова ни в орфографическом словаре, ни на сайте "Грамота.ру"

Comment: @виктор1799 смотрите церковнослаявянские словари

Answer (score 1):

Применять не следует. Его нет даже в Нацкорпусе. 
А что оно вообще значит? Я могу догадаться, но только догадаться.

Answer (score 1):

На слух приятнее как вариант "всякоразличный". Применим в качестве модальной вставки для оживления внимания собеседника - подобно обороту "в общем и целом".

Answer (score 1):

**Всеразличный** - *многообразный, разнообразный.*
[Полный церковнославянский словарь (с внесением в него важнейших древнерусских слов и выражений). Сост. свящ. Григорий Дьяченко. 1900.]

Примеры употребления:

*В религии Византизм означает Христианство, истинное и неизменное, отделенное от **всеразличных** ересей и расколов...*
[**Википедия, Византизм, 03. 05 2017**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC)

*Это выражается как во **всеразличных** законах, так и в абсурдных судебных процессах.*
[**Чем женщина отличается от человека, 2014**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=LP-hBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT87&lpg=PT87&dq=%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=CfCmt9pVA2&sig=Z8dRcE9-STRn-qFKxahKDbaYw0I&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiozsW-gY7UAhWsKJoKHS3cD4M4ChDoAQgeMAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE&f=false)

*Меня женщины всерьез не воспринимают, стойку на меня не делают, расслабляются и допускают **всеразличные** ошибки.*
[**А.Маринина, Закон трех отрицаний**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=7Gsi_UFjaaYC&pg=PT114&lpg=PT114&dq=%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE&source=bl&ots=e_TcaBMPr1&sig=t1cbg1t8YvN8-AWjlCBPQetrk6A&hl=et&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_oNjfgo7UAhWjE5oKHbOGAYs4ChDoAQg5MAU#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE&f=false)

*На него наезжали **всеразличные** желающие поживиться: таможенники, пожарные, санэпидстанция, налоговики, городские власти – все от него чего-то хотели, а договариваться с ними он не умел и взятки давать не хотел.*
[**А.Маринина, Ад**](http://litru.ru/book/?p=80107&page=25)

Да, *в современных словарях* слова "всеразличный" нет. Но посмотрите: используется же! - и всё понятно, и всё к месту, и заменять ничем не надо.
Возможно, настало время для того, чтобы ***всеразличный*** вернулся в язык.
Мне нравится, я возьму на вооружение.